# Is there a way to read 4 different arrays to generate a minimum and maximum value in a return function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, max, minimum

I have been working on a C Blood Pressure Tracker/Calculator application program and I have come across an issue in generating the minimum and maximum values of the inputted blood pressure values.
The expected output of the program is to return and display the Average Systolic & Diastolic, Minimum Systolic & Diastolic, Maximum Systolic & Diastolic, and Standard Deviation Systolic & Diastolic values.

## Last Update on this program

Hello there, you might be wondering has this program been solved? the short answer is no. but the long answer is I had to start over from scratch because I had been told by my lecturer that the program I was making did not meet the requirements on the task I was given. So 4 days ago was when I had to start from zero again and I was quite surprised that it took me 4 days to solve the program with the correct requirements even though the program code structure itself looks horrendous. In conclusion, the original program has been scrapped and restructured into a fully functional Blood Pressure Tracker Application. **THE END**

## The Program's expected function

The way the program is supposed to work is that it takes in user input from the 4 arrays and then uses the Standard Blood Pressure Formula (which usually starts from the second day) to calculate the Morning and Afternoon inputs to generate the output from each of the arrays and then the output are to be separated into Morning and Afternoon readings before going through the if and else if statements to determine whether or not the output values match the Standard Blood Pressure Category Chart, that is how the calAvg function works.

For the calMin and calMax function, it also works by getting the inputs from the 4 arrays but it does not use the Blood Pressure Category Chart nor the Blood Pressure Formula to generate its output but it basically reads the 4 arrays, finds the smallest or biggest value in each of the arrays, and then the output generated from the 4 arrays are then put into 2 separate arrays called minSYS, and minDYS(calMin function), maxSYS, and maxDYS(calMax function).

After they are put into the 2 separate arrays, the process of reading the 2 arrays begins in order to find the smallest and biggest value in Systolic and Diastolic.

## Actual output

But the actual output displayed by the program is this:(When 150 Systolic & 50 Diastolic is inputted)

Systolic Average : 150 mmHG
Systolic Minimum : 0 mmHG
Systolic Maximum : 12584792 mmHG
Diastolic Average : 50 mmHG
Diastolic Minimum : 0 mmHG
Diastolic Maximum : 268501009 mmHG

## UPDATE:

After doing some more experimentation, the output did not display what I expected but it showed this instead. And I have changed the SIZE of the minimum and maximum array since it made no sense to do that.
The current actual output when Systolic 150 & Diastolic 50 is inputted:
Systolic Average : 150 mmHG
Systolic Minimum : 0 mmHG
Systolic Maximum : 8140608 mmHG
Diastolic Average : 50 mmHG
Diastolic Minimum : 0 mmHG
Diastolic Maximum : 6421796 mmHG

Here is the code i used that generated that output:

```
int calMin(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE], int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE], int minSYS[SIZE], int minDYS[SIZE]) //wip
{
    int index, smallest1, smallest2, smallest3, smallest4;
    int smallestSYSTotal = 0, smallestDYSTotal = 0;
    //INITIALIZING smallest variables
    smallest1 = readMornSYS[0];
    smallest2 = readAfterSYS[0];
    smallest3 = readMornDYS[0];
    smallest4 = readAfterDYS[0];

     for(index=0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        minSYS[0] = smallest1;
        minSYS[1] = smallest2;
        minDYS[0] = smallest3;
        minDYS[1] = smallest4;
        if(smallestSYSTotal > minSYS[index])
        {
            smallestSYSTotal = minSYS[index];
        }
        if(smallestDYSTotal > minDYS[index])
        {
            smallestDYSTotal = minDYS[index];
        }

    }
    printf("Systolic Minimum : %d mmHG\n", smallestSYSTotal);

    return smallestDYSTotal;

}
```

I have tried to link the arrays into one variable and then tried do the standard method of finding and outputting the minimum and maximum values of the arrays but none of the methods have worked so far. and I have also tried changing the index values but after doing so, the whole program crashed.

and this is the full code to the program:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SIZE 7


int calSTDDEV(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE],int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE]);
int calMax(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE], int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE], int maxSYS[4], int maxDYS[4]);
int calMin(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE], int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE], int minSYS[4], int minDYS[4]);
int calAvg(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE], int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE]);
void displayHBPT(int avgHBP, int minHBP, int maxHBP, int stddevHBP);
void inputRead(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE],int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE]);
int main()
{
    int readMornSYS[SIZE], readMornDYS[SIZE];
    int readAfterSYS[SIZE], readAfterDYS[SIZE];
    int minSYS[4], minDYS[4];
    int maxSYS[4], maxDYS[4];
    int minHBP, avgHBP, maxHBP, stddevHBP;
    char userInput;

    //Title of the program
    printf("HBPTracker Application\n");
    printf("==================================\n");
    //Disclaimer of the program
    printf("DISCLAIMER: The HBPTracker Application is only capable of recording data for a week.\n");

    do
    {
        //This is the main menu of the program where you can decide to Start or Quit the program
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Do you wish to start<S> or quit<Q>: ");
        scanf(" %c", &userInput);
        //If the input is Start the input function will prompt out
        if(userInput != 'Q')
        {
            //The input function reads all of the 4 arrays
            inputRead(readMornSYS,readAfterSYS,readMornDYS,readAfterDYS);
            //The average function calculates the 4 arrays and then returns 2 values
            avgHBP = calAvg(readMornSYS,readAfterSYS,readMornDYS,readAfterDYS);
            //The minimum function scans for the smallest value in each of the 4 arrays
            //and then the output of the 4 arrays are put into two separate arrays to return two minimum values
            minHBP = calMin(readMornSYS, readAfterSYS, readMornDYS, readAfterDYS, minSYS, minDYS);
            //The maximum function scans for the biggest value in each of the 4 arrays
            //and then the output of the 4 arrays are put into two separate arrays to return two maximum values
            maxHBP = calMax(readMornSYS, readAfterSYS, readMornDYS, readAfterDYS, maxSYS, maxDYS);
            //The display function mainly displays the second return value of each of the other functions
            displayHBPT(avgHBP,minHBP,maxHBP,stddevHBP);
        }



    }while(userInput != 'Q');
    {
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("You have exited the program.\n");
        printf("==================================\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void displayHBPT(int avgHBP, int minHBP, int maxHBP, int stddevHBP)
{
    printf("Diastolic Average : %d mmHG\n", avgHBP);
    printf("Diastolic Minimum : %d mmHG\n", minHBP);
    printf("Diastolic Maximum : %d mmHG\n", maxHBP);
    //printf("This is where Standard Deviation would be %d\n",stddevHBP);

}

void inputRead(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE],int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE])
{
  int index, day = 1;
  char userInput;

    for(index=0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Day : %d\n", day);
        printf("Enter Morning Blood Systolic[Upper] : ");
        scanf("%d", &readMornSYS[index]);
        printf("Enter Morning Blood Diastolic[Lower] : ");
        scanf("%d", &readMornDYS[index]);
        printf("Enter Afternoon Blood Systolic[Upper] : ");
        scanf("%d", &readAfterSYS[index]);
        printf("Enter Afternoon Blood Diastolic[Lower] : ");
        scanf("%d", &readAfterDYS[index]);
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Do you wish to proceed to the next day?[Y/N] : ");
        scanf(" %c", &userInput);
        if(userInput == 'Y' && userInput != 'N')
        {
            day++;
        }
        else if(userInput == 'N')
        {
            break;
        }

    }

}

int calAvg(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE], int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE])
{
    int index;
    int calBPSYS1=0,calBPSYS2=0, avgBPSYS1=0,avgBPSYS2=0, totalSYS=0;
    int calBPDYS1=0,calBPDYS2=0, avgBPDYS1=0,avgBPDYS2=0, totalDYS=0;
   for(index = 1; index < SIZE; index++)
   {
    //Average Blood Pressure Formula 7 Days: Start(Day 2)
    //STEP 1 sum the values in each array
    calBPSYS1 += readMornSYS[index];
    calBPSYS2 += readAfterSYS[index];
    calBPDYS1 += readMornDYS[index];
    calBPDYS2 += readAfterDYS[index];
    //STEP 2 divide the total of Systolic and Diastolic arrays by the index of readings
    avgBPSYS1 = (avgBPSYS1+calBPSYS1)/index;
    avgBPSYS2 = (avgBPSYS2+calBPSYS2)/index;
    avgBPDYS1 = (avgBPDYS1+calBPDYS1)/index;
    avgBPDYS2 = (avgBPDYS2+calBPDYS2)/index;
    //STEP 3 add the average total of each array into their respective reading groups
    //and then divide by the number of systolic arrays(2) and diastolic arrays(2)
    totalSYS = (totalSYS + avgBPSYS1 + avgBPSYS2)/2;
    totalDYS = (totalDYS + avgBPDYS1 + avgBPDYS2)/2;
    if(totalSYS < 120 && totalDYS < 80)
    {
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Your Blood Pressure is NORMAL\n");
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Systolic Average : %d mmHG\n",totalSYS);
        return totalDYS;
    }
    else if(totalSYS >= 120 && totalSYS <= 129 && totalDYS < 80)
    {
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Your Blood Pressure is ELEVATED\n");
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Systolic Average : %d mmHG\n",totalSYS);
        return totalDYS;
    }
    else if(totalSYS >= 130 || totalSYS <= 139 || totalDYS >= 80 || totalDYS <= 89)
    {
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("You have HIGH BLOOD PRESSURE\n");
        printf("\tHYPERTENSION STAGE 1\n");
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Systolic Average : %d mmHG\n",totalSYS);
        return totalDYS;
    }
    else if(totalSYS >= 140 || totalDYS >= 90)
    {
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("You have HIGH BLOOD PRESSURE\n");
        printf("\tHYPERTENSION STAGE 2\n");
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Systolic Average : %d mmHG\n",totalSYS);
        return totalDYS;
    }
    else if(totalSYS > 180 || totalDYS > 100)
    {
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Your Blood Pressure is TOO HIGH\n");
        printf("Please consult a doctor immediately.\n");
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Systolic Average : %d mmHG\n",totalSYS);
        return totalDYS;
    }


   }

}



int calMin(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE], int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE], int minSYS[4], int minDYS[4]) //wip
{
    int index, smallest1, smallest2, smallest3, smallest4;
    int smallestSYSTotal = 0, smallestDYSTotal = 0;
    //INITIALIZING smallest variables
    smallest1 = readMornSYS[0];
    smallest2 = readMornDYS[0];
    smallest3 = readMornDYS[0];
    smallest4 = readAfterDYS[0];

    for(index=1; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        if(readMornSYS[index]<smallest1) //checking for smallest value in readMornSYS array
        {
            smallest1 = readMornSYS[index];
            minSYS[index] = smallest1;
        }
        if(readAfterSYS[index]<smallest2) //checking for smallest value in readAfterSYS array
        {
            smallest2 = readAfterSYS[index];
            minSYS[index] = smallest2;
        }
        if(readMornDYS[index]<smallest3) //checking for smallest value in readMornDYS array
        {
            smallest3 = readMornDYS[index];
            minDYS[index] = smallest3;
        }
        if(readAfterDYS[index]<smallest4) //checking for smallest value in readAfterDYS array
        {
            smallest4 = readAfterDYS[index];
            minDYS[index] = smallest4;
        }
    }
    for(index=1; index < 4; index++)
    {
        if(minSYS[index]<smallestSYSTotal)
        {
            smallestSYSTotal = minSYS[index];
        }
    }
    printf("Systolic Minimum : %d mmHG\n", smallestSYSTotal);

    for(index=0; index < 4; index++)
    {
         if(minDYS[index]<smallestDYSTotal)
        {
            smallestDYSTotal = minDYS[index];
        }
    }
    return smallestDYSTotal;

}

int calMax(int readMornSYS[SIZE], int readAfterSYS[SIZE], int readMornDYS[SIZE], int readAfterDYS[SIZE], int maxSYS[4], int maxDYS[4]) //wip
{
     int index, biggest1,biggest2,biggest3,biggest4;
     int biggestSYSTotal = 0, biggestDYSTotal = 0;
     //INITIALIZING biggest variables
     biggest1 = readMornSYS[0];
     biggest2 = readAfterSYS[0];
     biggest3 = readMornDYS[0];
     biggest4 = readAfterDYS[0];

    for(index=0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        if(readMornSYS[index]>biggest1) //checking for biggest value in readMornSYS array
        {
            biggest1 = readMornSYS[index];
            maxSYS[index] = biggest1;
        }
        if(readAfterSYS[index]>biggest2) //checking for biggest value in readAfterSYS array
        {
            biggest2 = readAfterSYS[index];
            maxSYS[index] = biggest2;
        }
        if(readMornDYS[index]>biggest3) //checking for biggest value in readMornDYS array
        {
            biggest3 = readMornDYS[index];
            maxDYS[index] = biggest3;
        }
        if(readAfterDYS[index]>biggest4) //checking for biggest value in readAfterDYS array
        {
            biggest4 = readAfterDYS[index];
            maxDYS[index] = biggest4;
        }
    }
    for(index=0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        if(maxSYS[index]>biggestSYSTotal)
        {
            biggestSYSTotal = maxSYS[index];

        }

    }
    printf("Systolic Maximum : %d mmHG\n",biggestSYSTotal);

    for(index=0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        if(maxDYS[index]>biggestDYSTotal)
        {
            biggestDYSTotal = maxDYS[index];
        }
    }
    return biggestDYSTotal;

}
```

Comment: In function `calAvg()` you have `for(index = 1; ...` yet (unlike `calMin()`) you have initialised the totals' variables with 0. What happens with element `[0]`? You also seem to have the averaging and reporting *inside* the summation loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane oh that is because the blood pressure formula says to skip the first input which would be index[0] so that is why I put index = 1 in the for loop, but for the totals' part I thought it was the standard to initialize the totals to 0?

Comment: [Please do not post images of texts (the output in this case) because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Texts should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Aside: *I thought it was the standard to initialize the totals to 0* - not if you set them to element `[0]` and loop from element `[1]` as I thought you might have intended.

Comment: You break the array bounds of the arrays length 4 ==> crash? Shouldn't the `minSYS[index] = smallest1;` be *after* the loop and (for example) `inSYS[0] = smallest1;` ?

Comment: The original intend for the length of 4 part was to put the output into two separate arrays to do the same exact reading again to narrow down the minimum into one output but I have no idea on how to implement that currently since I tried to copy the same structure from my calAvg function.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am not really sure, especially since I am still learning C.

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking the bounds of the arrays length `[4]` passed to the functions, indexing them in a loop which goes to `< SIZE` which is `7`.

I suggest you move some statements out of the loops and then something like this:

```
minSYS[0] = smallest1;
minSYS[1] = smallest2;
minSYS[2] = smallest3;
minSYS[3] = smallest4;
```

etc... and similar in other functions